# Is there a way to find history of websites which was opened through app browser?

Tags: applications, stock-browser, instagram, browser-history

I tried to find the websites I opened through apps like Twitter, Instagram; but I wasn't able to find them again. Is there a way to search for history of websites which was opened through app browser than using chrome or opera when opening them

Comment: If we talking about [Chrome Webview](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview) (which apps use to load web pages), it is highly unlikely, unless you search each app's data directory. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/21372155/4720957